# Merging multiple partials before rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Both partials below are elements of a table and have the same structure. So I wish to merge these two partials first and then render them to my ajax call. Is this possible?

```
def refreshprojects
  @projects = Project.get(params[:username])
  render :partial => "project.elements.data", :locals => {:projects=>@projects }
  render :partial => "project.shared.elements.data", :locals => {:projects=>@projects_shared }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering @projects and @shared_projects are array, you can just pass on them combined into a single array to one of the partials instead of doing that individually.

> render :partial => "project.elements.data", :locals => { :projects=> @projects + @projects_shared }

In case, if there is some difference in the partials for UI, you can call the two in a view with the name of the action, i.e., `refreshprojects.html.erb` and remove the two lines from the action.

> render :partial => "project.elements.data", :locals => {:projects=>@projects }
>
> render :partial => "project.shared.elements.data", :locals => {:projects=>@projects_shared }

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to create another view `refreshprojects`, and then render both partials inside it.

Then you would render `refreshprojects` to your ajax call.